# Does apple-app-site-association work with a web app?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I've just come across apple-app-site-association.

Will it work to open an iOS webapp (created by tapping Add To Homescreen while on a Safari webpage) as opposed to a native iOS app?

I have a URL link in a newsletter email we send out that I was trying to get to open the iOS user's webapp instead of their normal Safari.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't; The apple-app-association file contains the bundle id of the app to be launched.  Web apps aren't really apps and they don't have a bundle id, so they can't be launched

Comment: OK. Maybe Apple will allow that in the future. Or not.